# Python Multiprocessing Sharing Variables Between Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I'm trying to write a multiprocessing program which shares one or more variables (values or matrix) between the child processes. In my current test program I'm trying to spawn two processes, each sharing the num variable. Each adds 1 to the variable and then prints. However, whenever I try to run the program it tells me a TypeError has occurred, saying 'Synchronized' object is not iterable. How can I get this to work?

The code is shown below:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(num):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        num = num + 1
        print("process 1: %i \n" % num)
        if num > 50:
            break

def f2(num):
    while True:
        num= num + 1
        print("process 2: %i \n" % num)
        time.sleep(1.9)
        if num > 50:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(data))
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(data))
    p.start()
    j.start()
```

"Synchronized' object is not iterable results from running the program when it tries to create the first process:  p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(data))

I'm not sure whether using a queue would work as I'd eventually like to have a program which has a looping process and another which occasionally grabs the most recent result returned from the looping process.

Comment: The Synchronized object is a type of shared memory object provided by the multiprocessing module. It is designed to allow multiple processes to read and write to a shared memory location, but it is not intended to be iterated over.

Comment: How would I go about iterating the values over? Is there something I need to add to the subprocesses f and f2 in order to receive the values?

Comment: `num = num + 1` is a race condition, which is why they created `value.increment`, you also shouldn't copy `num`

Comment: would a mutex lock work like in this link work?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267715/how-to-use-lock-as-a-mutex-in-multiprocessing. I plan on using locks eventually but for now I'm simply trying to get the processes to talk to each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several issues with your code:

1. When you create a `multiprocessing.Value` instance (`num` in your case), you must use the `value` attribute of that instance to read or write actual value of that shared variable.
2. Incrementing such an instance, even if you replace `num.value = num.value + 1` with `num.value += 1` as I have done, is not an atomic operation. It is equivalent to `temp = num.value; temp += 1; num.value = temp`, which means that this incrementing must take place under control of the lock provided for such *synchronized* instances to ensure that the value is truly incremeneted. Otherwise, two processes may read the same value and increment it to the same final value and you will have only incremented the value once instead of twice.
3. The *args* parameter to the `multiprocessing.Process` initializer should be an *iterable* where each element of the iterable becomes an argument to your worker functions `f` and `f2`. When you specify `args=(data)`, the parentheses has no effect and is equivalent to simply specifying `args=data` and `data` is not an iterable. You needed to have `args=(data,)`. Note the comma (',') such that `(data,)` is now a `tuple` (i.e. an iterable) containing the single element `data` instead of a *parenthesized expression*.

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(num):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        with num.get_lock():
            num.value += 1
            print("process 1: %i \n" % num.value)
            if num.value > 50:
                break

def f2(num):
    while True:
        with num.get_lock():
            num.value += 1
            print("process 2: %i \n" % num.value)
            time.sleep(1.9)
            if num.value > 50:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(data,))
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(data,))
    p.start()
    j.start()
    p.join()
    j.join()
    print(data.value)
```

Prints:

```None
...
process 2: 47

process 1: 48

process 2: 49

process 1: 50

process 2: 51

process 1: 52

52
```

But note that in the above code, each process acquires and hold the lock for a very long time shutting out any other process from acquiring the lock. We can minimize how long the lock is held in the following way (and so the program will complete sooner):

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(num):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        with num.get_lock():
            num.value += 1
            saved_value = num.value
        print("process 1: %i \n" % saved_value)
        if saved_value > 50:
            break

def f2(num):
    while True:
        with num.get_lock():
            num.value += 1
            saved_value = num.value
        print("process 2: %i \n" % saved_value)
        time.sleep(1.9)
        if saved_value > 50:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(data,))
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(data,))
    p.start()
    j.start()
    p.join()
    j.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! So I guess get_lock() releases the data as soon as the indentation changes? How would this work with an array? Would I simply replace num.value with num.array?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the `with` block is exited a call to `release` is made on the lock. Look up *context management protocol* to see how this is accomplished. And yes, `multiprocessing.Array` is for creating a fixed size array of a specific type. Read the documentation for details. If my post has answered your question, then consider *accepting* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This clears the errors in your code. you need to make the args input a tuple. also, i pulled the values from the mp input. values print simultaneously so it appears to be working.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(num):
    num=num.value
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        num = num + 1
        print("process 1: %i \n" % num)
        if num > 50:
            break

def f2(num):
    num=num.value
    while True:
        num= num + 1
        print("process 2: %i \n" % num)
        time.sleep(1.9)
        if num > 50:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    data = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(data,))
    p.start()
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(data,))
    j.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps some, but while the error no longer shows up the print for each functions doesn't display anything. It seems the processes f and f2 aren't even being started now. if I disable the daemon I get the following TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Synchronized' and 'int'

Comment: my bad. i did not read carefully enough to see how the value impacted the code. i've edited my answer and that seems to fix it, although im not sure if it is what you are looking for

Comment: The program definitely seems to work for sending the initial value of 0 to each of the child processes, but they dont seem to share the calculations with each other (each child process adding 1 to num and storing it for the other, back and forth). I'm assuming I have to store the value back into the shared variable within each child process, but am unsure which command would work (would this be a mutex lock situation?). I also noticed each process only spits out a few numbers before the code ends, although the child processes dont seem to end on their own.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. i am not sure of a solution off the top of my head but ill think about it